# Navigation - how to use my own Local and Global costmaps?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, occupancy-grid

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have my own node that provides Global Map and Local Map as nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid messages.
I would like to use them in the navigation stack and I cannot figure out how to do it.

Have someone done this kind of operation?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300142/navigation---how-to-use-my-own-local-and-global-costmaps?/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 541 on 2018-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally speaking, you can just subscribe to the OccupancyGrid messages as a "static" layer

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2018-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-08-13**:
The maps are updated constantly (SLAM), I cannot use a static layer.
The Global map normally is updated at 1 Hz, the local map at 5 Hz

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-08-13**:
"static" is a bit of a misnomer. It will subscribe to the topic as long as you publish on it. Whether that's going to be efficient is another matter.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-08-13**:
Ok, I saw the code and I understood how it works.
Thank you you have been of great help

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-08-14**:
David, I have a last question for you. Can you explain me the meaning of the message "_updates"?
I have my idea about it, but I want to understand if I need to publish "myMap" and "myMap_updates" too...

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2018-08-14**:
You don't have to publish both, but publishing updates can be more efficient. If you have a 1000x1000 global map and change one pixel, you can either send the entire 1000x1000 map again or you can just send the update.

**Comment by [Myzhar](https://answers.ros.org/users/455/myzhar/) on 2018-08-14**:
Good, this is really important for me since I have this information.
The documentation of "map_msgs" is really poor.